# Fill an array with pairs of numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, numbers, project

I have a little programming project in C. I am really new to this topic so I appreciate every little help. The object is: I need to fill an array with pairs of numbers until the user types in -1. Then the user gives a command (Bigger or smaller) in the console. If the user types in smaller, then the program has to list every pair, that's first number is smaller than the second one.

I could write it until this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Max_Number 20

struct numberPairs {
    int firstNum, secondNum;
};


struct numberPairs input(){
    struct numberPairs firstInput;
    printf("Please give me the first number! \n");
    scanf("%d", &firstInput.firstNum);
    printf("Please give me the second number! \n");
    scanf("%d", &firstInput.secondNum);
    return firstInput;
}

struct numberPairs ArrayInput (struct numberPairs x){
    struct numberPairs array[Max_Number], pairs;
    int index=0;
    do{
        pairs=input();
        array[index]=pairs;
        index++;
        if (pairs.firstNum == -1 || pairs.secondNum == -1){
            break;
        }
    }while(index<5  );
}



int main (){
    struct numberPairs t;
    ArrayInput(t);
}
```

Basically I don't know how to do it any further.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [_How To Ask A Good Question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [_How To Create A Minimal, Complete, And Verifiable Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where is it failing or where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make `array[Max_Number]` a global array as now it is an array that is local to the `ArrayInput` function and is gone when the function returns. By making it global, it will stay and can be used by other functions. The function now is of type `void ArrayInput(void)`.

After calling `ArrayInput` in main you now have the array. Now ask the user for larger or smaller and then go through the array to list the elements meeting the user's requirement. You can do that as a new function that uses the global array.

Comment: and don't forget that the two values could be equal

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helped me out guys:)

Answer (score 0):

You should do steps like :

1. handle input until `-1`
2. use `fgets` handle "smaller" or "Bigger"
3. output

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Max_Number 20

struct numberPairs {
    int firstNum;
    int secondNum;
};

struct numberPairs input() { 
    struct numberPairs firstInput;
    printf("Please give me the first number! \n");
    scanf("%d", &firstInput.firstNum);
    if (firstInput.firstNum == -1)
        return firstInput;
    printf("Please give me the second number! \n");
    scanf("%d", &firstInput.secondNum);
    return firstInput;
}

void ArrayInput() {
    struct numberPairs array[Max_Number];
    int index = 0;
    do {
        array[index] = input();
        if (array[index].firstNum == -1)
            break;
    } while(++index < Max_Number);
    while (getchar() != '\n')
        ;
    printf("Please input Bigger or smaller\n");
    char buf[1024];
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
    if (strcmp(buf, "Bigger\n") == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i != index; ++i)
            if (array[i].firstNum > array[i].secondNum)
                printf("%d %d\n", array[i].firstNum, array[i].secondNum);
    } else if (strcmp(buf, "smaller\n") == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i != index; ++i)
            if (array[i].firstNum < array[i].secondNum)
                printf("%d %d\n", array[i].firstNum, array[i].secondNum);       
    } else {
        fputs("Input wrong.", stdout);
    }
}

int main (){
    ArrayInput();
    return 0;
}
```